# Создаю бот в телеграмме, который "тащит" данные из БД. Но что-то не так в синтаксисе запроса

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, psycopg2

Создаю бота в телеграмм, который из локальной БД запрашивает данные Юр лица по нескольким атрибутам.Не работает скрипт запроса:

```
def askInn(message):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    inn = message.text
    if not inn.isdigit():
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ИНН должен быть целым числом. Попробуйте еще раз')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, askInn)
        return
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Спасибо, идет обработка запроса')
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test.test WHERE value1 = '{}'".format(inn))
        #connection.close()
```

Соединение с базой есть, сообщение 'Спасибо, идет обработка запроса' выходит. Но результат запроса нет. В БД (postgres) столбец INN имеет тип данных text

Вот библиотеки:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import psycopg2
```

Comment: Есть какая то ошибка? или просто результата нет? Не вижу где Вы вообще его получаете. Должно быть что-то типо `data = cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: Так вы ничего не делаете с запросом, вы его выполнили и все.

Comment: asanisimov, ошибки нет. Просто нет результата

Comment: Так у вас в коде нигде не написано, что этот самый результат надо получить и куда именно его поместить.

Comment: execute только выполняет запрос. Чтобы получить результат запроса нужно выполнить метод fetch или fetchall (о чем вам написали в первом комментарии), и с этими данными что-то потом сделать (например, показать пользователю). Вы в коде этого не делаете, поэтому и результата нет.

Comment: Ваши данные находятся в объекте cursor, как вам подсказал выше @asanisimov, вам поможет извлечь данные `cursor.fetchone()` или пройтись по `cursor.fetchall()`